# ObjectDisposedException for TCPClient.Close in System.dll?

Tags: c#, exception

Im using a Request System called xNet and it seems ObjectDisposedExceptions are occuring which on-occurence causes a HUGE cpu spike, sometimes continuously keeping CPU at 99-100% causing freezes and lag.

The script mentioned is the following:
https://github.com/PR4GM4/xNet-Ameliorated

An example code is:

```
using (HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest()) {
    string url = "https://httpbin.org";
    string[] proxysplit = proxy.Split(':');
    httpRequest.Proxy = new InternalProxyClient(ProxyType.HTTP, proxysplit[0], int.Parse(proxysplit[1]), null, null);
    httpRequest.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    httpRequest.ConnectTimeout = 15000;
    httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    HttpResponse hr = httpRequest.Start(HttpMethod.GET, new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), new StringContent(""));
    if (hr == null) return "2";
    string sr = hr.ToString();
    if (sr == null) return "2";
}
```

(If a list of half/dead proxies are needed, I can provide it, just im not sure if linking to them is allowed or not.)
**Big note here, it seems to only ever occur whenever theres some kind of other exception like failing to connect to the proxy, or a general bad response, so good connection proxies and/or no proxy at all never has this issue (unless again a general failed error).**
If you loop this code, and give it a dead proxy (And to speed things up, multi-thread it to around 5 a time) it will eventually cause an exception like bad response or a timeout and eventually an objectdisposedexception.
I tried debugging in Visual Studio but it gives me almost no information, Historical Debugging gives no information just "Source not found".

[image]

Call Stack for the First Exception Thrown of the ObjectDisposedException in the screenshot above.

[image]

Seems to be related to line `1430` in `~Http/HttpRequest.cs` or line `217` in `~Proxy/ProxyClient.cs` as it's the only line I know to exist thats to do with EndConnect socket and also coincidentally can produce ObjectDisposedException. Just not sure how to properly handle the exception here without causing the rest of the script to fail. Also why does a simple exception here cause so much CPU spike?

Strangely enough, no matter how I wrap an exception handler for ObjectDisposedException it never gets triggered, no matter how much code or where I wrap? (On both scripts)

```
try
{
    tcpClient.EndConnect(ar);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    connectException = ex;
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks Sorry if being stupid here, but what stack trace exactly?

Comment: The stack trace of the exception.  Turn on Break on All Exceptions in Debug, Exceptions.

Comment: Looks like a bug in that library to me.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah its a bug in it and seemingly to do with the socket connection? Tryna fix it as the old developer doesnt seem to be actively working on it and is russian. (xNet Ameliorated is my version of it with some stuff removed and updated, the bug occurs on both my version and the original).

Answer (score 1):

I found out why, it wasnt because of the .EndConnect on either of the 2 files, it was actually caused by the .Close() calls, since it does .EndConnect inside of that, thats why I couldnt see any "Source" etc.

So it was causeed because the socket connection wasnt connected, so doing .Close() would cause the Exception.

It was a simple fix.
(Where tcp = a TcpClient)

Do the following instead of just tcp.Close()

On Timeouts (Where it's most likely if never at all connected):

```
if (tcp.Client.Connected) {
    tcp.GetStream().Close();
    tcp.Close();
}
```

When it might be properly connected:

```
if (!tcp.Connected) {
    if (tcp.Client.Connected) tcp.GetStream().Close();
    tcp.Close();
}
```